# MVVM - Business Layer Where do Mapping?

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, architecture, prism, datamapper

I have a solution where i need **MAP** my objects from **Model(MVVM) to Entities(EF) and vice-versa.**

Right now, im doing it inside of the View Model the MAPPING:

```
 Sistema.DataEntities.Models.Cliente clifinal = new Sistema.DataEntities.Models.Cliente();//EF Entities Model
 clifinal.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(ObCliente);//convert View Model to EF
 _clienteService.ClienteService_Update(clifinal);//update on BLL(Service Layer)
```

The correct is do it on the Business Logic Layer?

If i do it on BLL, this layer will need to know about Models(MVVM) and thats not a good thing for the architecture since im using PRISM 5 and modules.

After this i created this only to show a correct architecture from my eyes.

[image: Layers of Project]

I thing thats the good way... But im very stuck on the dependencies thats creates and all of the patterns(PRISM)... on this point of **MAPPING**. **Where i do the MAP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the ViewModel has nothing to do with the business layer, and the business layer doesn't have to know about the ViewModel, the View Model should be (un)mapped in the model layer.

To remove the dependency from EF, what you must do is to define the entities in a separate project. In you do so:

- The Data Layer EF will depend on entities
- The Business Layer will depend on entities
- The Model will depend on entities

These are not anomalous dependencies.

To get a better decoupling, it would be possible to make yet another set of business layer entities, independent from the EF POCOs. In that case:

- The Data Layer would depend on business entities
- The Business layer, would naturally depend on business entities
- The Model would also depend on business entities.
- The EF entities would only exist in the EF layer

This is the ideal decouplign, but it's not free: you need two mapping layers. So you have to get a balance between the advantages of decoupling an the cost of decoupling. That depends on the project size, how many maintenance is expected, and so on.

You can do a mix of them: some of the POCOs can be also business entities, and some of them not.

Comment: Your answare is very confuse to me... You have some examples or links?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have links. But, for example, for the first option: create a project named "Entities" which contains all your classes, and depends on nothing. Then, when you implement the "Data" project with EF, add a reference to "Entities" and use them  (perhaps you can use them directly as your EF Code First classes, or you need to do some mapping). Do the same with your "BusinessRules" project. In your "Web" layer, add the same reference, so you can use the entities to deefine your view model. Now, if you change the data layer, you can create a new one with other technology that...

Comment: ...makes a reference to the entities project and uses them. If this project has the same classes that the original EF Data project, the rest of the application will continue working. To make a better separation, make a "DataInterface" project that contains the desired functionality. Make a reference to "DataInterface" from the business layer, and later on, you can implement this interface in any way you want and provide it to your business layer.

Comment: Ok... now its very clean since my english is not very good... thanks for help.